# EventViewer: Custom view Ok button grayed out

Tags: windows-10, event-viewer

I am trying to create a Custom View by Source in Event Viewer. But when I do this, the OK button is grayed out. Does anyone know how to solve this?

I am using Windows 10, and the Event Viewer is run under Administrator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Event Sources box is a dropdown list and doesn't accept a comma-separated list of numbers. You need to select your sources from the drop-down and then add your event ID's to the box below